# Dict - If more than one value per key, extract the last element

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict the looks like the following (though there is 1.5mil+ pairs) :

```
{'key1' : 10,
'key2' : 20,
'key3' : [30,40],
'key4' : 50,
'key5' : [60,70,80],
'key6' : 90}
```

99% of my keys have a single value, however for the keys that have an array of values.. I'd like to instead return the last element.

So my resulting dict would be flattened and unique;

```
 {'key1' : 10,
'key2' : 20,
'key3' : 40,
'key4' : 50,
'key5' : 80,
'key6' : 90}
```

From my searches I think a list comprehension would likely be the best way but I'm just not sure how to do it. Particularly because not every key contains the same data type.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple dict comprehension will do:

```
d = {'key1': 10,
     'key2': 20,
     'key3': [30, 40],
     'key4': 50,
     'key5': [60, 70, 80],
     'key6': 90}

d = {k: v if not isinstance(v, list) else v[-1] for k, v in d.items()}
#        ^ if v is not a list taking v as it, otherwise taking the last element
print(d)
```

Outputs

```
{'key1': 10, 'key2': 20, 'key3': 40, 'key4': 50, 'key5': 80, 'key6': 90}
```

Of course the inverse will also work:

```
d = {k: v[-1] if isinstance(v, list) else v for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: just an FYI in case anyone needs it - my lists were actual numpy arrays so I had to change it to `{k: v if not isinstance(v, np.ndarray) else v[-1] for k, v in d.items()}`